# Chosen placeholder value wont change from default?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-chosen

Im using the jquery plugin Chosen to mask a Html.Listbox as a muli selection tool. It works great except that I need to change the default text. I've tried setting the placeholder text both in the html and by way of jquery. Here is the relevant code...

```
@Html.ListBox("Filter-Chooser",aList,new { @class = "chzn-select filter-chooser") 

function EnableMultiChoose() {
    $(".chzn-select").data("placeholder", "Filter By...");
    $(".chzn-select").chosen();
}
```

I've also tired specifying the parameter @placeholder = "Filter By ..." to no avail.I've checked the html output and it appears to set the placeholder property...

Html Rendered

```
<select class="chzn-select filter-chooser" id="Filter-Chooser" multiple="multiple" name="Filter-Chooser" placeholder="Filter By...">
<option value="Content">Content</option>
<option value="Author">Author</option>
<option value="DeckName">Deck Name</option>
...
```

Any ideas on how to specify the placeholder properly?

Comment: you should try reading the docs. http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/

Comment: (because you're setting in wrong in the html and you would see that if you had read the docs)

Comment: @roasted, where are you seeing that in the docs?

Comment: Here: http://davidwalsh.name/jquery-chosen

Comment: But using it here, strangely doesn't work : http://jsfiddle.net/x69HJ/

Comment: That's probably because those aren't actual docs, it's just some guy's blog. I linked to the actual docs.

Comment: Some guy's blog, btw, that is over a year old, whereas chosen was updated 24 days ago.

Comment: @Colleen  Nice point, thx for the input

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I will help:
Use "data-placeholder" attribute.

```
<select class="chzn-select filter-chooser" id="Filter-Chooser" multiple="multiple" name="Filter-Chooser" data-placeholder="Filter By...">
```

Comment: This should be the correct answer, as its language agnostic and it's the simplest answer.

Answer (score 4):

Okay, specify the placeholder via the data-placeholder attribute. cool.

```
@Html.ListBox("Filter-Chooser", aList , new Dictionary<string,Object> { {"class","chzn-select   filter-chooser"}, {"data-placeholder","TEXT HERE"}})
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using simple_form you will need something like:

```
<%= f.input :education_ids, :label => false, :collection => Education.all, :input_html => { :data => { :placeholder => 'Education' }} %>
```

Answer (score -2):

solution as below.

```
$("[value='Select Some Options']").val("your text");
```

Comment: What happens when user's locale changes to another language?

Comment: i have not tried for another language as i didnt came across such requirement. you can check it.